# what is the correct form for "tex file.tex | dvips | ps2pdf"?

Tags: pipe

I would like to streamline 3 commands into one, but I keep getting error message.

```
tex | dvips | ps2pdf file.tex
```

or possibly

```
tex file.tex | dvips | ps2pdf
```

Then `divps` says there is no file.   Or I might try

```
tex file.tex > dvips > ps2pdf
```

Then I do get `file.dvi` but does not get handled by `dvips`.  It's dangerous to guess this way and I clearly don't understand the `>` and `|` operators.

What is the correct way to run all 3 commands?  The fact that this is TeX hardly matters.

Comment: Try `make file.pdf` or `pdftex file.tex`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `make: *** No rule to make target 'text.pdf'.  Stop.`

Comment: you will probably need to use appropriate switches for all the commands that you are using to take data from appropriate streams (stdin) and write them to appropriate streams (stdout). It might not be default. Did you open manual pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the output file is always the original name with the extension changed (unless you specify something other with command switches) so you could do this instead of piping.

```
tex file.tex; dvips file.dvi; ps2pdf file.ps
```

This executes the commands one after the other. I don't think the tex command has any way of outputting the result of its processing to `stdout` so you can't do piping with it.

EDIT:

As per Jeff's suggestion then this is a better way since the remaining commands are only executed if the previous command returns a successful exit status, that is status 0.

```
tex file.tex && dvips file.dvi && ps2pdf file.ps
```

Comment: Suggestion: change the semicolons to && so that subsequent commands only run if the previous ones were successful